# how to get axios to load when row is expanded?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a dynamic table that has two axios.get methods. My methods work and the data get added to the table but I would like networkGroup to load only when I click toggle to expand a row. I can only get NetworkGroup to load automatically. How do I get it to work?

Here is my code:

```js
toggle(gpId) 
        {
            this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'isExpanded',               !this.networkGroups[gpId].isExpanded);
        },
async getData(currPage) 
        {
            const skip = (currPage - 1) * this.page.top;
            const response = await this.axios.get(`/s/groups`, {
                params: {
                    skip: skip,
                    top: this.page.top,
                },
            });
            this.page = response.data.pages;

            for (const audience of response.data.data)
                await this.getNetworks(group.id);
            
            this.groups = response.data.data;
        },
        async getNetworks(audId) 
        {
            try
            {
                const response = await this.axios.get("/s/groups/network-groups?gpId=" + gpId);
                               
                if (!this.networkGroups[gpId])
                {
                    this.$set(this.networkGroups, gpId, {});
                    this.$set(this.networkGroups[gpId], 'isExpanded', false);
                }
                    
                this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'data', response.data ? response.data.data : []);
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                if (error.message && error.message.includes("404"))
                {
                    if (!this.networkGroups[gpId])
                    {
                        this.$set(this.networkGroups, gpId, {});
                        this.$set(this.networkGroups[gpId], 'isExpanded', false);
                    }
                        
                    this.$set(this.networkGroups[gpId], 'data', []);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            }
                
        },
```

```html
<td class="audience-column">
                <!-- expand button -->
                <div class="ex_btn">
                  <span @click.prevent="toggle(group.id)">
                    <font-awesome-icon
                      :icon="
                        (networkGroups[group.id].isExpanded)
                          ? 'caret-down'
                          : 'caret-right'
                      "
                      :class="[
                        'dropdown--arrow fa-2x cl-blue-primary relative t-3 g-link',
                      ]"
                    />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </td>
```

Not sure what I should change. Thanks!

Comment: Just call `getNetworks` within your `toggle` method?

Answer (score 0):

seems it's not calling anything whenever you toggle the expand button, toggle method should call the `getNetwork` methods

try this:

```
toggle(gpId) {
  this.$set(this.networkGroups[audId], 'isExpanded', !this.networkGroups[gpId].isExpanded); <<<--- change this

  this.getNetwork(gpId) <<-- into this

  },
```

and i think you set the wrong argument on `getNetwork` method:

```
getNetworks(audId) <<--- it says audId
{ 
            try
            {
                const response = await this.axios.get("/s/groups/network-groups?gpId=" + gpId); <<--- but this calls gpId
                 ....
```

hope my answer helps you!